# Why am I not inheriting the superclass variable?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, superclass

I am outputting

```
SubClass subClass = new SubClass(4);
System.out.println(subClass.getVal());
```

With these two classes:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public int x = 99;

    public int superClassMethod() {
        return -1;
    }
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int x;

    public SubClass(int value) {
        x = value;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

This outputs `4` as expected. But let's say I comment out the line `x = value` in the `SubClass` constructor. Why does it output `0` (I assume a default for uninitiated variables) and not `99`, inherited from the superclass?

If I change `return x` to `return superClassMethod();` it seems to correctly pull `-1` from the superclass. So why the method and not the variable?

Comment: The default value for `x` in SubClass is `0`, omit the deceleration in SubClass and you will have your `99`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When variables have conflicting names from different scopes, it always uses the variable from the nearest scope, even if it isn't set to anything yet.

To distinguish variables in other scopes, prepend the variable with `this` or `super`:

```
public class SuperClass {
    protected int x;
}
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private int x;
    public SubClass(int x) {
        x = 2; // sets the parameter variable
        this.x = 2; // sets the instance variable
        super.x = 2; // sets the super class' instance variable
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is great because it also illustrates a related scenario, i.e. local scope overriding a member variable of the same class.

Comment: Is there any reason for passing in `x` to `method()`? It's getting overwritten anyway. Couldn't I do `int x = 2;` instead?

Comment: The only reason for putting the `x` in the parameter instead of doing `int x = 2;`, is because it's a typical issue when people make setter methods for the parameter to have the same name as the instance variable.

Comment: Do you mean something like `void setX(int x) { this.x = x;}`?

Comment: Not quite. I should probably have put a constructor there instead.

Answer (score 3):

Line `public int x;` means new definition of variable named `x`. As a result you will have two variables named `x` in the class - the one within `SuperClass` and another one in `SubClass`. They have different location and therefore can contain different values. As you don't initialize the one within `SubClass`, its default value is `0`.

If you remove the declaration in `SubClass` completely, any access to `x` from `SubClass` will access the variable `x` from the parent classes.

Comment: So if I have declared `x` in the child class, how would I get the parent's value of `x`? `this.x` versus `super.x`?

Comment: Just a note - you really shouldn't declare two variables that hide one another. It isn't that good of practice. Just name them two different things (variables should generally be named more descriptively than x anyway). The answer by @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 will work so I upvoted it, but in general it's not that good of an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're inheriting, but your explicit re-declaration of `x` in your daughter class overwrites `x` in your daughter class' scope.

Omit `public int x;` in `SubClass`, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Subclass also has an int with the same name x. It will then print that default value and not that of your super class.

Try to remove that int, and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

this all because of this piece of Code.

```
public SubClass(int value) { //what ever You pass you will get the result.
        x = value;
    }
```

Here `x` is an instance Variable So, In inheritance only `Methods` are allowed to be `override` never a `Instance Variable` So, `x` will Initialize either by `0` if `new SubClass()` Used.
 Or,   `x` with  `value` if `new SubClass(int value)` Used.

you are calling

```
SubClass subClass = new SubClass(4);  //initialize your local x with 4
System.out.println(subClass.getVal());    // Result you will get is 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `x` inside `SubClass` is the [shadowing variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). that is it hides the SuperClass variable `x`. So you cant get the value from SuperClass. When you commenting `x = value;` its returning default value for `int` member of class i.e. `0`.

Comment: No, you can still access the variable in the superclass. See the other answers

Comment: @4castle definitely we CAN access using ``super`` keyword! but OP is not doing that. When we call the variable using only name then Super class variable hidden by subclass. That's I'm  trying to explain. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a member in both subclass and **superclass**, in the instance of the object subclass the x that is visible is that one you defined in subclass, if you need the **superclass** x you need to use the super keyword.

therefore the only x valid in that scope is the one of the instance in the **subclass**

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public int x;   // this line hides the x defined in the super class.
    ...

    public int getVal() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Because the x in SubClass hides the x defined in SuperClass, and because there is no scope specified for

```
return x;
```

javac translates it as

```
return this.x;
```